# Google SignIn using OAuth 2(mobile app with server)

Tags: node.js, flutter, oauth-2.0, google-openid

I'm trying to implement google sign in on a flutter mobile application, for that I used(https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) and configured on the google developers console a new project, to that project I added two credentials(one for the server and one for the mobile app), here's what the code on the app lookes like

```dart
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(clientId:"XXX_MOBILE");
final result = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
final authenticationData = await result.authentication;
//authenticationData.idToken returns a valid idToken
```

From there I send this token to the server where I'm using(https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library) to verify the idToken

```js
const googleClient = new OAuth2Client("XXX_SERVER");
const ticket = await googleClient.verifyIdToken({
 idToken: data.idToken,
 audience: ["XXX_MOBILE"], //audience only mentions the mobile client id and not the server
});

const payload = ticket.getPayload();
console.log('payload', payload);
```

The output of such verifyIdToken call is **"invalid token signature"**, any clue what I might be missing or what wrong step I took? Thanks

Comment: https://medium.com/@shubham.narkhede8/flutter-social-media-login-and-get-and-insert-data-into-mysql-database-da21c9752a7d

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede Thank you, but I'm actually trying to implement it without firebase